# parse php array in salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, soap

I am trying to integrate salesforce with a third party application,so i am getting response as below:

```
[
    apex_schema_type_info=(https://mijn.pensioenperfect.nl/soapdoc/calculator.php, false, false), 
    field_order_type_info=(waardeOP, waardePP, waardeWZP), 
    waardeOP=895.16, waardeOP_type_info=(waardeOP, https://mijn.pensioenperfect.nl/soapdoc/calculator.php, null, 1, 1, true),
    waardePP=626.62, waardePP_type_info=(waardePP, https://mijn.pensioenperfect.nl/soapdoc/calculator.php, null, 1, 1, true),
    waardeWZP=0.00, waardeWZP_type_info=(waardeWZP, https://mijn.pensioenperfect.nl/soapdoc/calculator.php, null, 1, 1, true)
 ]
```

I need help in parsing this response?

Comment: Is there no way to have a JSON response? This can be parsed but won't be a reliable and scalable solution.

Comment: Yeah, pass it in as JSON. Then you get native deserialization.